# Docker container restart via rest api

Tags: docker

I have been referring to `https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/` to see how to start a docker container. When we start docker containers via command directly, we can specify things like `--restart` and put a restart policy.
How do I do that via REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the restart policy can be specified when we **create and start** the container using `docker run`, so you should expect to find this functionality in the `POST /containers/create` endpoint that creates containers.

As you can see in the docs there is indeed a `RestartPolicy` field in the `HostConfig` object field of container description JSON.

---

*On the side note*: technically speaking, using docker commands is a less direct way because docker's CLI is actually using the REST API itself.